# Statistical learning and expected value

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, loss-functions

I'm studying some statistical learning theory. If i have $X$, $Y$ as random variables representing the data-labels samples drawn from a certain distribution and a loss function, it is right to say that:
$$ E[loss(Y, f(X))] = \sum_{x\in X} loss(y, x) * p(x)$$

If i'm correct that means that the expected risk of my classifier $f()$ on $X$ is the probability of drawing some $x$ times its $loss$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In statistical learning theory we pretty much always are considering the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and the expected value here is with respect to that distribution, not just the marginal distribution of $X$. In general
$$
\text E[L(Y, f(X))] = \int_{\mathcal X \times \mathcal Y} L(y, f(x)) \,\text dP(x, y)
$$
where this notation unifies the discrete and continuous cases. If both are discrete this integral becomes
$$
\sum_{x, y} L(y, f(x)) p(x, y)
$$
but it still is over all possible values of $X$ and $Y$. Intuitively we want to make sure we're considering what our losses are over the full range of $X$ and $Y$ while weighting on the joint density of those values since they likely aren't independent so it matters how they interact. Also what you wrote would still be a random variable since it has $Y$ in it, so it would make comparing risks harder.

Comment: You're right. Because Y is also a random variable, so obviously i must consider the joint distribution of X and Y.

Also, i read that the optimal bayes classifier is the best possible predictor. I'm wondering if it is the best possible predictor for every x in X or just the "average" best predictor (it has the lowest risk over X average or on every x). It is a little bit confusing

Comment: @tucossss the optimal bayes classifier is the classifier that minimizes the expected loss, which in that case is the probability of a misclassification. This article has the proof in the binary case and it makes it clearer what exactly they're talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_classifier. And in case you haven't seen it, we can use the fact that $P(A) = \text E\mathbf 1_A$ to move between probabilities and expectations so that's why we can talk of $P(f(X) \neq Y)$ as if it was an expected loss (the loss is 0-1 in this case)

Comment: now it is more clear, i was confusing the bayes classifier with its risk. Thank you for the explanations.

Comment: @tucossss yeah for sure! Glad this helped